# 2 exercises in Linux with permission

Tags: permissions

I have 2 exercises to do and I have no idea how to do it.

1. Show the listing of directories in /etc, where Other don't have any access permission.
2. Show the listing of directories, where Group has "read" and "execute" as an access permission.

I tried with this but it didn't work:

```
/etc$ find . \! -perm /o+- | ls -l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close - however

- `ls` doesn't accept files on its standard input. You can either use `-exec ls -ld {} +` or just use the `find` command's own `-ls` which gives similar information
- the question asks for directories, so you should probably add `-type d`. You may want to add `-maxdepth 1` to prevent recursive listing
- the `/perm` form is tricky; I suspect you want `/o=rwx` for the first case. See if you can figure out the second case for yourself